# I have a new project, but when execute ng serve, I get error

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, node-modules

I need to change this topic, I cant post new topic.
I have update the script, and install new package.
I still get errors but not the one I post last.

```
                             _                           _  _
  __ _  _ __    __ _  _   _ | |  __ _  _ __         ___ | |(_)
 / _` || '_ \  / _` || | | || | / _` || '__|_____  / __|| || |
| (_| || | | || (_| || |_| || || (_| || |  |_____|| (__ | || |
 \__,_||_| |_| \__, | \__,_||_| \__,_||_|          \___||_||_|
               |___/
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 8.12.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 6.1.9
@angular/cdk: 6.4.7
@angular/common: 6.1.9
@angular/compiler: 6.1.9
@angular/core: 6.1.9
@angular/forms: 6.1.9
@angular/http: 6.1.9
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/platform-browser: 6.1.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 6.1.9
@angular/platform-server: 6.1.9
@angular/router: 6.1.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 6.1.9
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
```

I get this errors now. and this is new error that i dont now how to fix.

```
WARNING in ./~/ng2-webstorage/dist/app.js
11:35-46 "export 'OpaqueToken' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
6128:45-70 "export 'ConnectedOverlayDirective' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
13725:44-56 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
15765:42-54 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
16831:48-60 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
17553:48-60 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
18421:48-60 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
19726:48-60 "export 'OverlayState' was not found in '@angular/cdk/overlay'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
139:16-23 "export 'trigger' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
140:20-25 "export 'state' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
140:38-43 "export 'style' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
144:20-25 "export 'state' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
144:36-41 "export 'style' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
148:20-30 "export 'transition' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts
148:54-61 "export 'animate' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
53:16-23 "export 'trigger' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
54:20-25 "export 'state' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
54:38-43 "export 'style' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
59:20-25 "export 'state' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
59:36-41 "export 'style' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
64:20-30 "export 'transition' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
64:53-60 "export 'animate' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
65:20-30 "export 'transition' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/angular2-semantic-ui/components/accordion/accordion_panel.ts
65:53-60 "export 'animate' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

And I can't find answer to this errors. I hope, I can find an answer now, so I can keep on with this script.

Comment: Can you try an `npm i` and try again? It seems that you are not in the rigth folder anyway

Comment: did try again with npm i, but result with the same error...

Answer (score 34):

I would recommend reading this:

https://www.techiediaries.com/updating-angular-cli-projects/

On this page it states:

**Angular 6 uses angular.json instead of angular-cli.json.**
This can be achieved using :

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

This solved my issue.

Good luck

Comment: I have tryed with ng update @angular/cli, now i get this error: This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.

Comment: You need run **npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest** @Niklas

Comment: I have also tried this and got this error `Cannot destructure property createHash of 'undefined' or 'null'`

Answer (score 23):

Angular 6 looks for angular.json instead of angular-cli.json.

You need to update your `@angular/cli`. Adding to the above answer

I did update all the package with the following commands and updated all dependencies too. So as to remove all compatibility issues with other packages.

If you are starting your app or demo app, follow this procedure. Be extra careful if you are doing this for production app.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
ng update @angular/cli
npm install
```

**Install npm-check-updates**

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

**Use ncu to update your package.json**

`ncu` for display

`ncu -u` for re-writing your package.json

**Update your @angular/cli to modify your application to be compatible with angular 6**

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

[image]

and run `npm install` to update your packages

Answer (score 3):

Re-Install @angular/cli

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the official upgrade guide which will tell you what you need to do for your own particular needs:

[image]

https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just needed to close/reopen my terminal after I had remove/reclone a repo. Not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be caused by different version of angular-cli is installed. 
I just created a new project, using new command, then copied across the src directory. then compiled them all successfully.

```
    ng new UX7
```